# docker: structure needs cleaning

Tags: docker

I'm getting this error now when trying to install an image

docker run -it ubuntu bash

```
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
952132ac251a: Pulling fs layer
82659f8f1b76: Pulling fs layer
c19118ca682d: Pulling fs layer
8296858250fe: Pulling fs layer
24e0251a0e2c: Pulling fs layer
docker: open /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob134909549: structure needs cleaning.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried deleting the docker machine. Didn't fix it. What do I do?

Comment: try to remove docker-machine and remove `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker` directory. may be layer is corrupted.

Comment: I had this problem when I'd run out of disk space

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured out why i was getting this error. In this case I did not have my docker machine set as active in docker-machine.

```
$ eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Docker desktop application you could try selecting Troubleshoot from the main menu and

- Clean / Purge data
- Reset to factory defaults

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error could be corrupted partition.

Running `fsck` after un-mounting the disk should fix it.